# Contours and Closed Path

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, contour-integration

> [image]

Sorry, but I thought I am very good in complex analysis, but then I saw this question which makes me question myself "**Is closed path different from contours?**"

Now I know the difference between them by the logic that contours have orientation.

> This problem is from Chapter 9 of *Complex Analysis* by Ian Stewart and David Tall.

But still to be frank, I honestly dont know how to prove this, as I can see that there is no orientation mentioned of $\gamma$, this is not a contour.

But still **I don't think so it is the correct way to prove it.**
I plotted the sketch and yes it is closed, but I feel there must be some analytical way to prove this is closed but not a contour?

Please let me know or solve it please?

Comment: The orientation on the curve $\gamma$ comes from letting $t$ start at $0$ and end at $1$. What is your textbook's definition of a *contour*? Does it require that the curve be simple? smooth? By the way, the problem is slightly wrong; they should have $t\in (0,1/2]$ and $t\in (1/2,1)$ (although doubly defining at $t=1/2$ is OK when the two formulas agree there).

Comment: The problem is from complex analysis by Ian Stewart chapter 9

Comment: You still haven't told us what the definition of a *contour* is. Note that $\gamma$ is a curve that retraces its own steps — a forward curve followed by the same curve in reverse. Does that fit his definition?

Comment: There's not any ..I check the whole chapter do you know about homotopy?

Comment: @TedShifrin Doesn't defining it to run only on $(0, 1)$ (and not the endpoints) keep it from being closed?  Probably should keep one of them?

Comment: @learningstudent It is highly unlikely a definition isn't given.  Where does the index say "contour" appears?  Maybe it has something to do with differentiability at the wild spot near $0$ or something.

Comment: Actually I'm not having the book.. I just saw It on Google books.. let me check there again... To view the definition

Comment: You shouldn't ask a question if you cannot supply the necessary information.

Comment: @rschwieb: The author defined $\gamma(0)=\gamma(1)=0$ at the beginning, so that covers that. :)

Comment: I'm guessing a contour has to be a simple closed curve, so that it can enclose a well-defined (oriented) region. Yes, this function fails to be $C^1$ at $t=0$ and $t=1$, as well. Why did the author not just take a line segment from A to B and then return from B to A?

Comment: @TedShifrin Pfft.  Lost in the details I guess

Comment: @TedShifrin I wondered the same thing (the line segment) in a now-deleted comment :/

Answer (score 1):

It seems that a contour is defined as "made up of a finite number of smooth paths which have non-zero continuous derivatives". See p.91.

Your path is continuous (note that $\lim_{t \to 0} \gamma(t) = \lim_{t \to 1} \gamma(t) = 0$). However it is not differentiable at $t = 0, 1$ since
$$\dfrac{t + it\sin(\pi/t)}{t-0} = 1 +i\sin(\pi/t)$$
does not have a limit as $t \to 0$.

Comment: +1 More formally, on page 130 of the same book (second edition 2018): "a *contour* is a path of the form $$\gamma = \gamma_1 + \cdots + \gamma_n$$ where $\gamma_1, \ldots, \gamma_n$ are smooth paths such that the final point of $\gamma_r$ coincides with the initial point of $\gamma_{r+1}$ for $r = 1, \ldots, n-1$."

Comment: Hmm, what does smooth mean if not at least $C^1$? So piecewise smooth. But it bothers me that the contour needn't enclose a region, if we're going to prepare for the Cauchy Integral Formula, etc.

Comment: @TedShifrin In the present Complex Analysis book "smooth" means in fact $C^1$ (Definition 6.5 on p.115). To define complex line integrals $\int_\gamma f(z)dz$ we can use any piecewise smooth curve $\gamma$, even it is not closed or doesn't enclose a region. But of course the interesting theorems require closed curves.

Comment: I've taught complex variables, both undergrad and grad, numerous times. I'm just making the point that questions need to include attempts, and certainly need to include relevant definitions of terms.